# Rails kaminari: How to specify total_count for paginate?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, performance, pagination, kaminari

COUNT query to find out total_count sometimes very slow.
But if I am caching values of items_amount or such field in model I want to use it for kaminari pagination.

EXAMPLE: I have model

`Category (:id, :title, :items_amount)`

And then on show view I want to

`<%= paginate @items, total_count: @category.items_amount %>`

So like paginate_array, but in paginate. It is very useful for perfomance.

Is there a feature like this or how I can add it?

Like `will_paginate` gem, where we can do it like this
`.paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 72, total_entries: @category.items_amount)`

Answer (score 2):

Kaminari just calls the `total_count` method on `@items` in order to get the count. By default this does the `SELECT count(*) ...` query but you could decorate `@items` to be something that provides your cached count.

If you are just generating page links though then `paginate` will take a `total_pages` option. By providing the page count it means that the `paginate` call doesn't need to get the total count. (I can't find that option explicitly documented but it is in the code and I've tested using it).

```
paginate @items, total_pages: @cached_page_count
```

`@cache_page_count` might have a value like `(@category.item_amount / 30.0).ceil` in order to get the correct page count with 30.0 being your page size.

Answer (score 0):

I think they answer this really well in their gems readme? https://github.com/kaminari/kaminari

You can do this on controller level using `paginates_per` to set the limit on each page and `max_paginates_per` to set the limit of pages?